# How does the legacy/UEFI bootloader know where to find the stage two bootloader?

Tags: linux, windows, boot-loader, uefi, bios

Most systems I have been exposed to format their disks very simply with only `boot` and `rootfs` partitions. Others also have `recovery` (like Windows) and `swap`, but I am trying to keep it simple.

I have not read any standard that specifies in which partition the bootloader has to be. I have never read anything regarding whether there even *has* to be a boot partition. Of course, the designation of a partition as `boot` is moot; we just need some partition that is loaded into memory and executed by the stage one bootloader (legacy/UEFI).

So, my question is: How does the stage one bootloader find the second stage bootloader? Does it:

- Expect a partition table?
- Read the partition table from disk (or whatever medium you are booting from) and check each for a bootable file?
- Expect the second stage bootloader to be in the first partition?

I would assume the second from the list above, but that is a result of only speculation. I use Linux as a main OS, but I imagine this early boot process is OS-agnostic.

Comment: What is the boot flag for on a partition? Does it, stage one boot loader, read the partition table and select the one with the boot flag, if none then the first partition?

Comment: @jc__, Boot flag makes sense. I forgot about that being there. That aside, the boot partition does not just have a single binary. I have read documentation suggesting that the partition *must* be FAT32 formatted, for example. On my Linux box the bootloader binaries are located at `EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi` and `EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.efi`. This seems to imply some sort of standard filesystem and directory structure.

Comment: bios/EFI loads, sets up the hardware to a point, then it will jump to the MBR on the drive. The MBR will contain grub or ... and that will point it to the binaries on a drive... Sound right? just lost why the boot flag is there though...

Comment: @jc__, This is the exact question I am asking. The process you describe is correct. I am just wondering exactly where it looks and what the expectations are for the format of the bootloader binaries and filesystem in which they sit. The process is such that the early bootloader (legacy/UEFI) does early system testing and configuration. It maintains a boot priority hierarchy in which it will look at mounted drives, optical disks, hard disks, etc for a bootable system. It is at this stage (once it finds a bootable medium) I am curious exactly what the process looks like.

Comment: It seems that the boot flag is an indication of whether or not the partition has a bootable binary, but what of filesystem and directory structure? The contents of the partition is what matters. A partition table can set the boot flag for an empty partition. It seems the flag is just a hint about where to look. Does the bootloader have to sit in `EFI/Boot` and be named `BOOTX64.efi`, as is the case with my system? These are the kinds of things I am hoping to have answered.

Comment: bios has hdd0 set as the boot device. The bios loads on power up, then will look at the the standard location for that boot device. (HDD first 512 bytes, floppy on sector X, on CD location Y). The binary there is a bare-metal compiled binary will be able to read an expected file system and the location for the next stage of the bootloader, if 2 stage, or load the OS.

Comment: So if grub is used (on the first 512 bytes) it will be able to read vfat, ntfs, extX file systems and search for its second stage on the bootable partition or the first partition at a predetermined location. (EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.efi -- for EFI; /boot/grub/* -- for bios)
If the windows boot loader is used it will be able to read ntfs, vfat, others it will look for the binary NTLDR (or other) in a predetermined location. So if your setup has EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.efi and you change that the bare-metal binary will not know where to look.

Comment: BUT then there is the boot sector of the partition. I may have this all confused.

Answer (score 3):

We need to differentiate between the legacy system (BIOS) and UEFI,
because they are very different. On a non-UEFI PC, or a UEFI PC
running in legacy mode, the boot process goes like this: first the
BIOS loads the MBR boot sector into RAM and starts executing the boot
code. Because the boot sector is only 512 bytes long and also contains
the partition table, the boot sector cannot contain code that
understands the internals of even the simplest file systems. GRUB
solves this by installing additional code in sectors 1-62 on the hard
drive. This area of the drive is more or less "no man's land" between
the boot sector and the start of the first partition. This so called
"Stage 1.5" can read files from a filesystem, and it loads GRUB Stage
2 and configuration files from the /boot directory.

The firmware in flash memory on the motherboard has evolved since the
early days of the BIOS. Whereas the BIOS is able to read the first
sector of a fixed set of devices, the more modern UEFI systems
understand the FAT32 file system directly in the firmware. When a UEFI
system boots, it first looks for the EFI System Partition. The disk
containing the system partition must have a GUID Partition Table
(GPT), and the system partition is recognized by its fixed GUID. The system
partition should be a FAT32 partition from which the firmware reads
and executes the boot loader. Alternatively, the first program to be
loaded can also be a boot manager, which allows the user to choose
which boot loader (and consequently which operating system) should be
executed. The UEFI can also be configured using variables that are
stored in non-volatile memory on the motherboard.

Comment: BIOS: In that 512 bytes the first 446 bytes contain the boot loader the next 64 bytes the partition table, and the last 2 bytes the identifier.

Comment: BIOS: The 446 byte boot loader contains a jump to the "no mans land".